# Unable to set image properties using CSS

Tags: html, css

I think I am doing something dumb. I have an existing web site, I'm trying to move as much of the presentation code as I can into the stylesheet. I have some dated experience of both html and css.

I have a stylesheet, which includes the following...

```
.social-sites-img {
  width:24px;
  height:24px;
  vertical-align:bottom; 
}
```

and

```
.social-sites {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
 right: 3px;
 top: 10px;
}
```

...and I have a piece of HTML which includes the following...

```
<body class="window">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="page">
            <!-- ==== START MASTHEAD ==== -->
            <header class="masthead" role="banner">
                <div class="logo"><img src="images/xxxxx.gif" alt="xxxxx" /></div>
                <div class="social-sites">
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/xxxxx" target="_blank">
                        <img class="social-sites-img" src="images/facebook.png" alt="Visit xxxxx on Facebook" />                
                    </a>
                    <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/xxxxx" target="_blank">
                        <img src="images/linkedin-icon.png" alt="View xxxxx's LinkedIn profile" align="bottom" width="24" height="24"/>             
                    </a>            
                </div>
```

The plan is to display a couple of social media icons, plus links, in the top corner of the page.

Before I started messing, the html for both icons looked the same, just like the "LinkedIn" element above. So, hardwired height, width and alignment. Ant the code displayed as intended. Having moved the "Facebook" element into CSS, I am seeing the following:

[image]

In other words, it looks like the stylesheet data is not being picked up. The only problem with this, is that looking at styles applied to the rest of the page, other things within the stylesheet *are* being picked up.

Off the back of this, I really have two questions:

- is it immediately obvious to anyone what is happening here? If it helps, I am using Chrome on the development box, but will expect the finished site to work across the board
- are there any off-the-shelf tools that I can use, a browser plugin for example, which will help me to better see what styles are being applied to particular elements? So that if this comes up again, I have a head start?

Things I have tried so far have been mainly to do with the name of the class, also using a unique class (`social-sites-img`) as opposed to piggybacking off e.g. `social-sites.a.img`. But my lack of understanding of the overall topic is holding me back somewhat here as well.

Comment: What css do you have for .social-sites ?

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Maybe some CSS definitions overrule your width and height properties. Just post more of your CSS and we might be able to help you.

Comment: thanks for prompt comments. I have added the CSS for social-sites, if you think any more of the css would be useful , please say.

Comment: @user3760661 in what sense? do you mean a workaround? I guess so, but the object of the exercise really is to clue up on css as much as anything, so workarounds won't necessarily help with that.

Comment: thanks @beeef, I'll start stepping up the classes tomorrow, but if you think it would be useful to post some more of it (warning, there is quite a lot!) please say

Comment: @PeteH clear your cache, try a different browser, and verify your css file is linked in the header. I'd also create another style and see whether that gets created and other styling is applied. This hit me a couple months back on my own site, and I had to set 5 different no-cache settings to make sure things updated properly. Also check that you're not missing something like a close quote or a broken HTML tag somewhere in the code.

Comment: It usually helps to put your `img` on `display: block`. If I'm correct by default they are `inline` elements and inline elements don't listen to dimensions e.g. `width` and `height`.

Comment: Did you solve your problem already?

Comment: @beeef yes, and I have just posted an answer

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got it sorted with only the following minor tweaks:

```
.social-sites img {
width: 24px;
height: 24px;
vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

and

```
<div class="social-sites">
    <a ...
        <img src="images/facebook.png" alt="Visit xxxx on Facebook" />              
    </a>
    <a ...
        <img src="images/linkedin-icon.png" alt="View xxxx's LinkedIn profile" />               
    </a>
</div>
```

So I'm kind of left with a situation where it works, but I'm not sure exactly what I did to make it work.

I do remember this kind of thing happening when I used to do web programming quite regularly (over 10 years ago now) but I guess I was hoping that there were fewer "random" effects these days. I still can't see anything wrong with my original code (and I ended up trawling through lots of css code, d'oh!).